# Passing an array w/ getJSON()

Tags: jquery, arrays, getjson

I have a form with several selects.  I have a js function which, when called, builds a two dimentional array of the selects ids and the selected values in them:

```
function sendQueryPredicates(){
priorID = null;
id = null;
var predArray = new Array();
$("select option:selected").each(function () { // finds all selected options from all selects
    id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    if(id != priorID){
        //make a new subarray
        predArray[id] = new Array();
        i = 0;
    }
    text = $(this).text();
    predArray[id][i] = text;
    priorID = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    i++;
});
$.getJSON("ajaxJQ_server.php", // server page called by jquery
{ // Data sent via ajaxJQ
    "callingForm": "queryForm",
    "callingElementID" : "jQquery_btn",
    "callingState": "query",
    "thisPasses": predArray['cageType'][0],
    "thisDoesntPass": predArray
},
submitMouseQueryCallBck  //function executed after return from ajax/jquery call to server
);
}
```

When I examine the `$_GET` array over on the server the `"thisDoesntPass": predArray` is missing while   the `"thisPasses": predArray['cageType'][0]`, does get passed.

Can I not pass array in this method?  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that jQuery will correctly convert a 2d array to a querystring. You will probably need to `JSON.stringify` your array and pass it like that.

Comment: What does `predArray` look like?

Comment: predArray is a 2D array containing strings. First index is a string consisting of the id of the selects and the second a numeric index.  It will also be a "ragged" array (ie. there will be a varied number of second level indexes per first level index.

Comment: I tried: var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(predArray);  all it seemed to create and pass was a string "[]"!

Comment: It appears I can pass a 1D array but not a 2D.  So what am I doing wrong as to the JSON.stringify?